# Internal server error while trying to build an api using a function that takes *args as parameters, in Flask

Tags: python, rest, flask, internal-server-error, args

I have a function which returns me a vector.

```
def class_vector(*categories):
    all_categories = categories
    model = Word2Vec.load(r"C:\Users\vector.model")
    my_dict = dict({})
    for idx, key in enumerate(model.wv.vocab):
        my_dict[key] = model.wv[key]
                   
    categories_vectors = dict({})
        
    for i in all_categories:
        if i.lower() in my_dict.keys():
            categories_vectors[i] = my_dict[i]
                  
    average_vector = np.mean(list(categories_vectors.values()), axis =0)
    average_vector =  average_vector.reshape(1, -1)

    return average_vector
```

Now I call this function:

```
vector_generator_object = class_vector("apple", "banana")
```

This works perfectly and returns me a vector for the fruits. The above function is in a .py file called vectors_list.py

Now I want to build an api that takes the fruit names as input from a user and use the `class_vector` function to return the computed vectors.

Api code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from vector_list import class_vector

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def status():
    fruits = request.args.getlist("param")
    str_fruits = ",".join(fruits)
    returned_vec = class_vector(*str_fruits )
    return returned_vec
```

Now I do `flask run` from cmd &  `curl "http://localhost:5000?param=apple&param=banana"`. This returns me `500 Internal Server Error`. Any idea how to fix this

Comment: While there is an answer as to what is causing the 500 error, you should focus instead on practicing your debugging skills. Before the function begins, `print(request.args)`, wrap a try/except (temporarily) around parts of the code you think might be breaking. Put in print() break points.

Unfortunately flask does sometimes fail to give you a better response than 500 even if you are in debug mode (you are right?) and especially if you are behind some kind of server like NGINX.

Comment: Can you please help me with the answer. I can tell you what I have tried till now. I have tried with hardcoding  the return value from `request.args.getlist("param")` and it worked fine for function calls. Now I wanted to apply the same findings in the api but getting this error. I am using a virtual env so thinking of checking the versions of the package dependencies. But if you could please help me understand why you think it's breaking, will really be of much help

Comment: I ran with debug=true and getting this `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a ndarray`

Answer (score 0):

Your flask code looks fine. I think the issue is with your `class_vector`. It will be helpful if you can add the `traceback` for the same.

Comment: I ran with debug=true and getting this `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a ndarray`

Comment: you are returning ndarray not a valid return for flask. Try to return this ```{"data": returned_vec.tolist()}``` from the  ```status``` function

Comment: return str(returned_vec) worked. Dict was also throwing an error. Thanks a lot for the inputs

Comment: I am getting the same vectors for different input combinations which is wrong. Any idea why this is happening

Comment: maybe it's something related to your model. Try adding print statements after every important line, and see where it's failing.